# Can atomic read operations lead to deadlocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I am watching [this Herb Sutter's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4) about atomics, mutexes and memory barriers, and I have a question regarding it. Since `47:33` Herb explains how mutexes and atomics are related to memory ordering. On `49:12` he says, that with the default memory order, which is `memory_order_seq_cst`, atomic `load()` operation is equivalent of locking a mutex, and atomic `store` operation is equivalent of unlocking a mutex. On `53:15` Herb was asked what would happen if the atomic `load()` operation in his example was not followed by subsequent `store()` operation, and his answer really confused me:

*54:00 - If you don't write this release(*`mutex.unlock()`*) or this one(*`atomic.store()`*), that person will never get a chance to run...*

Maybe I completely misunderstood him due to my not very good English skills, but this is how I interpret his words:

*If a thread `A` reads an atomic variable without subsequent write into it, no other thread will be able to work with this variable due to it being deadlocked by the thread `A` like as if a mutex was locked by this thread without further unlocking.*

But is it really what he meant? It doesn't seem to be true. In my understanding release happens automatically right after an atomic variable was either loaded or stored. Just an example:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> number{0};

void foo()
{
    while (number != 104) {}
    std::cout << "Number:\t" << number << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thr1(foo);
    std::thread thr2(foo);
    std::thread thr3(foo);
    std::thread thr4(foo);
    number = 104;
    thr1.join();
    thr2.join();
    thr3.join();
    thr4.join();
}
```

In the above example there are 4 threads successfully reading the same atomic variable, and no any writes are needed in these threads to release the variable for other threads. Apparently, `atomic.load() != mutex.lock()` as well as `atomic.store() != mutex.unlock()`. They may behave the same way in terms of memory barriers, but they are not the same, aren't they?

Could you please explain to me, what did Herb actually mean by saying they are equal?

Comment: There are 5 threads, don't overlook the one that calls main().  That 5th thread performs a store, thus allowing the 4 other threads to make progress.

Comment: `number = 104` is a shorthand for `number.store(104)`. Your example does too perform a store.

Comment: Yes, but after 1 `store()` in the main thread there are 4 loads happen in additional threads. If every `load()` operation is the same as locking a mutex, why don't the program hangs on joining deadlocked threads?

Comment: In the `memory_order_seq_cst` mode, no other thread can modify the variable before the initial thread has done, hence stalling.

Comment: *Can atomic read operations lead to deadlocks?* I'm not about to watch an 80+-minute-long video and I doubt I'm alone in that, but if `std::atomic<>` could deadlock like that, it wouldn't be an atomic type.  Are you sure you have the context of the statement correct?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: "Are you sure you have the context of the statement correct?". No, and this is why I am asking. It seems I just misinterpreted the message as Pete Becker explained in his answer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Mine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here. An atomic read, regardless of memory order, is **not** "equivalent to locking a mutex". In terms of **visibility** it might have the same effects, but a mutex is much heavier.

Here's a typical problem with a mutex:

```
std::mutex mtx1;
std::mutex mtx2;

void thr1() {
    mtx1.lock();
    mtx2.lock();
    mtx2.unlock();
    mtx1.unlock();
}

void thr2() {
    mtx2.lock();
    mtx1.lock();
    mtx1.unlock();
    mtx2.unlock();
}
```

Note that the two function lock the two mutexes in the opposite order. So it's possible that `thr1` locks `mtx1`, then `thr2` locks `mtx2`, then `thr1` tries to lock `mtx2` and `thr2` tries to lock `mtx1`. That's a deadlock; neither thread can make progress, because the resource it needs is held by the other thread.

Atomics don't have that problem, because you can't run code "inside" an atomic access. You can't get that sort of resource conflict.

The issue that seems to underly that discussion is the possibility that the thread running `while (number != 104) {}` won't see the updated value of `number`, and so the code will be an infinite loop. That's not a deadlock. Which isn't to say that it's not a problem, but the problem is with visibility.

Comment: "The issue that seems to underly that discussion is the possibility that the thread running while (number != 104) {} won't see the updated value of number". Yeah, I understand now, it seems this is what he is talking about. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Your example _can_ deadlock, but it's not a practical demo because the deadlock only will happen when `thr1` manages to lock `mtx1` and `thr2` manages to lock `mtx2` before either one of them reaches the second `.lock()` call. The window of opportunity for that is extremely small. If you'd put something that takes a bit of time—a `sleep()` call—in between the two `.lock()` calls in one or both of the two thread functions, then that would greatly increase the liklihood of the deadlock actually happening.

Comment: @SolomonSlow -- the code is there to illustrate **what** a deadlock is. It's not intended to be a "practical demo".